# Roslyn - Throw build error

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, code-analysis, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

Looking through Roslyn's documentation, I could not find anything about failing the build. I have currently built an analyzer tool that will look to see if methods are missing a tag and notify the developer with a suggestion to add this tag. But what I want to do is be able to fail the build if they attempt to build the project.

I saw places online where devs have been using: `CodeIssue` but I do not think this would work.

This would be similar to how stylecop works when it fails the build.

Has anyone found any examples/resources where it can return a build failed with errors?

Comment: What kind of analyzer is it? Are you talking about a subclass of `DiagnosticAnalyzer`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the compiler options to treat your analyzer's warning ID as an error, just like with built-in warnings.

Comment: i.e. "this should just work", as long as you've added your analyzer to your project.

Comment: How do you change the compiler option? I looked in the properties of the project but can not find this option

Comment: @SLaks, Thanks that does make sense. But setting the analyzer as a warning does not actually output a warning number since it's part of the "intellisense" warning and not the "build" warning. Could we hard code a warning number to be passed?

Comment: @user1965106: The analyzer declares a warning number in its diagnostic.

Comment: @SLaks, it turns out that this is returned as an intellisense warning and not a build warning resulting in a successful build even when passing the warning number. Is Roslyn only connected to the IDE and intellisense?

Comment: @user1965106: Analyzers are passed to the compiler too.  Did you install it as a VSIX into VS or from NuGet into the project?

Comment: @SLaks I installed it as a VSIX extension. Would I need to pass it through nuget in order to have it part of the compile errors?

Comment: Yes; VSIXes do not affect your project at all.  You need to install it in the project.

Comment: @SLaks, I exported my solution to a nuget project and installed it to a test project to see if it works. This approach did not kick off any build errors neither any IDE errors

Comment: Did it actually add an analyzer reference to the test project?

Comment: @SLaks, I packaged my analyzer project into a nupkg file and added it to my test project. It then got installed when I added missing nuget packages and it added a reference of my analyzer dll to my test project. I assumed it would behave the save way as adding an extension through a VSIX installation, but this one did not show any IDE errors (as it formally did) neither did it display any build errors while compiling. Any suggestions? Thank you SLaks

Comment: You need to add it as an analyzer reference, not a normal reference.  The Analyzer project template includes a NuGet project that is correctly configured to do that.

Comment: @SLaks, Having a lot of problems getting it to run through the Analyzer reference. I created a new solution for VSIX templates on visual studio and when I add the dll to the analyzers, it fails the build and throws the error which is what was expected. When I added my logic, it seems like the analyzer does not pick up any of my rules, but when I install it through the VSIX extension, visual studio picks up the rule and errors and throws the IDE error. Been through all the documents on this, any other advice?